# Global in jest puppeteer custom test environment loses context in test

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I'm writing a npm module to reduce the boiler code in my test project and this module will be added as a dev dependency in that test project. I'm using prototype inheritance to extend an existing class(Page) of puppeteer library as well in this npm module.

When I create a global browser in custom test environment and use it to create page instance in the test. The Page class loses reference to all properties I have added to it using prototypal inheritance. And it throws error `page.sendText is not a function`

But when I create the browser instance in the test. I am able to use the properties I have added to Page class.

Creating global.browser in custom test environment.
Creating browser instance in test.

GLOBALSETUP in npm module

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(await puppeteer.launch({some config});
```

TEST ENVIRONMENT in npm module:

```
this.global __BROWSER__ = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
});
```

Extended PAGE class in npm module:

```
const Page = require('puppeteer/lib/Page').Page;

Page.prototype.sendText = async (selector, text) => {
    let element = await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});
    await element.type(text);
}
```

Test in test project after locally installing the npm module:

```
describe('awesome test', () => {
    it('something will be ok', async () => {
      const context = global.__BROWSER__.defaultBrowserContext();
      page = await context.newPage(); 
      await page.goto('https://google.com/')
      await page.sendText('#search', "puppeteer")
      await page.screenshot({path: 'google.png', fullPage: true})
    })
});
```

The error is -> page.sendText is not a function
I was expecting the sendText would work.

Comment: There isn't method named `sendText` in puppeteer API

Comment: yeah I added it - 
```
Page.prototype.sendText = async (selector, text) => {
    let element = await this.waitForSelector(selector, {visible : true});
    await element.type(text);
} ```

Comment: Why you do this? There is really nice method named `.type` to type anything in inputs/textarea

Comment: Well that's not the point here but to answer let say I have to getText from element and I don't want ten people writing test using ten different ways to do that so I will add a function Page.prototype.getText = async function(selector) { return await this.$eval(selector , element => element.innerText) }. Consistency in test project is what I wanted to achieve.